# Which $n$ to use in the formula for standard error of a proportion

Tags: standard-error

This question may be obvious to many but is not to me. I have found many variants on this question on CV but either they're not quite what I want or I don't understand them.

I need to graph some error bars on a graphs of proportion success and failures within two groups.

These are my data

```
library(dplyr)

(df <- data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:2], each=2),
                  success = rep(c("fail", "success"), times=2),
                  count = c(45,10,36,13),
                  tot = rep(c(55,49), each=2)))

# output
#   group success count tot
# 1     a    fail    45  55
# 2     a success    10  55
# 3     b    fail    36  49
# 4     b success    13  49
```

Now for the proportions within each group

```
(df <- df %>% mutate(prop = round(count/tot,2)))

# output
#   group success count tot prop
# 1     a    fail    45  55 0.82
# 2     a success    10  55 0.18
# 3     b    fail    36  49 0.73
# 4     b success    13  49 0.27
```

Now the formula for $se_{prop}$ is the square root of ($p$ x $(1-p)$)/$n$), where $n$ is the number of observations, but is $n$ the total $n$ in each cell,

```
(df <- df %>% mutate(se1 = round(sqrt(prop*(1-prop)/count),2)))

# output
#   group success count tot prop  se1
# 1     a    fail    45  55 0.82 0.06
# 2     a success    10  55 0.18 0.12
# 3     b    fail    36  49 0.73 0.07
# 4     b success    13  49 0.27 0.12
```

...or is it the total $n$ in each group...

```
(df <- df %>% mutate(se2 = round(sqrt(prop*(1-prop)/tot),2)))

# output
#   group success count tot prop  se2
# 1     a    fail    45  55 0.82 0.05
# 2     a success    10  55 0.18 0.05
# 3     b    fail    36  49 0.73 0.06
# 4     b success    13  49 0.27 0.06
```

...or is it the total $n$ across *all* groups?

```
(df <- df %>% mutate(grandTot = sum(count),
                     se3 = round(sqrt(prop*(1-prop)/grandTot),3)))

# output
# group success count tot prop grandTot   se3
#     a    fail    45  55 0.82      104 0.038
#     a success    10  55 0.18      104 0.038
#     b    fail    36  49 0.73      104 0.044
#     b success    13  49 0.27      104 0.044
```

Comment: Google 'error bars on bar charts' to fetch some instructive tutorials. But error bars are not a substitute for revealing the sample sizes in the chart or its caption.

Comment: $n$ is total sample size.

Comment: is that right @user2974951?! Ok I have amended my question to include that possibility. If you frame your comment as an asnwer I'll accept it.

Comment: No, my mistake, $n$ is total sample size for each group. If I understand correctly, you have multiple groups which are all independent, mutually exclusive. In which case you would estimate the proportions and SD for each group separately.

Comment: Thank you, @user2974951, yes different groups. I imagine it would be the same principle if the groups were measured at different timepoints: *n* would be the number in each separate group at each separate timepoint?

Comment: Yes, if you were to separate your data in such case, say A1 and A2, then these would be two distinct groups, so proportions would be estimated separately.

Comment: Great thank you.